# How to implement complex entity relationship in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

I have a family of entities which look something like this:

```
Company (1    ->    n)  CompanyContact  (n   <-    1) Contact
     \                                                  /  
      \                                                /
       \  (1    ->    n)    User    ( 1     -      1) /
```

To reiterate,

Company has a OneToMany relationship with CompanyContact (which is just an entity that links Company, Contact and a parameter) and a OneToMany relationship with User

Contact has a OneToMany relationship with CompanyContact and a OneToOne relationship with User

This structure has been growing steadily as our business needs are refined and they are set to be complicated even further by additional entities in the future.

The problem can then be demonstrated with the following example:

When I create a User, I set the proper Company and Contact before persisting, and the User is persisted correctly. However, the Company and Contact entities in the db are still oblivious to their relationship with the newly-created User.

If I want to keep all my entities updated do I really need to update the entire Company-CompanyContact-Contact-User chain every single time? Is there a better way to do this?

I've tried applying different cascading strategies the the relationship mapping on the User side, e.g.

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Contact contact;

but this still doesn't update the Company and Contact side.

Comment: Sorry but without posting your code you will not get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your classes are not well designed.

Try to add **targetEntity**

> (Optional) The entity class that is the target of the association.
>   Optional only if the collection property is defined using Java
>   generics. Must be specified otherwise.

And **mappedBy**

> The field that owns the relationship. Required unless the relationship
>   is unidirectional.

maybe those would help :

[oracle docs](http://%20https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html)

[jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read the articles and will try eliminate as many bidirectional relationships as I can.